# REST API Raw Data passing in Jmeter 2.4

Tags: jmeter

I am working on REST API application and one of the requests I need to send raw body data  e.g.:

`->gcim_client_uuid ,value:-11111111111111111111191000000002`

Can anyone suggest how can we do in Jmeter?

Comment: Any feedback on this ? You should accept answer if it helped

Answer (score 0):

Use JMeter 2.9 and HTTP Sampler has a Raw Post Data tab where you can put your body.
Read:

- http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request

> Since JMeter 2.6, you have the option to switch to Post Body when a request has only unnamed parameters (or no parameters at all). This option is useful in the following cases (amongst others):
>       GWT RPC HTTP Request
>       JSON REST HTTP Request
>       XML REST HTTP Request
>       SOAP HTTP Request
>   Note that once you leave the Tree node, you cannot switch back to the parameter tab unless you clear the Post Body tab of data.
>   In Post Body mode, each line will be sent with CRLF appended, apart from the last line. To send a CRLF after the last line of data, just ensure that there is an empty line following it. (This cannot be seen, except by noting whether the cursor can be placed on the subsequent line.)

2.4 version is rather old now, you shouldn't be using it anymore.